# Is it possible to change PHP error layout (i.e. orange box)?

Tags: php

Is it possible to change the way PHP formats its error messages? I'm on PHP 5.3.5, using the default error output settings, and was hoping I could change the layout in some .ini or config file. The standard way PHP displays error message I find somewhat hard to read.

For clarity, I'm talking about errors that are displayed on my page. Also, I'm not talking about different types of errors. I'd just like to change the orange box and exclamation mark and the way the call stack is displayed. As the error is rendered in my browser, perhaps there's a template somewhere in the installation files that I could change?

I apologize to all orange-box disciples out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "orange box" is created by [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/), an extension to PHP, not PHP itself. I looked at the configuration settings briefly and was not able to see an easy way to change the formatting, although it is open-source, so you could theoretically do whatever you wanted with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent xdebug from overloading the display but it'll only get worse IMHO. You'll need to check your php.ini file for the exact switch.